# What is the correct (Most effective) Cucumber Project Layout when Considerring Page Object Modelling?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, cucumber

What is the correct (Most effective) Cucumber Project Layout when Considerring Page Object Modelling?

After allot of research I have come up with the following design:

*Maven Project*
[image]

NEW PROJECT SETUP:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the main idea you present, however the page object model also refers to the utilites.  One of the desired goals of the page object model is to keep the selenium code out of the test itself, so most of those references will go to the pages, then its locators and actions would access the driver class, preferably through the utilities.  That does not mean that the test program cannot make direct references to the utilities, but it should do so for non-selenium reasons only.  There are exceptions, of course.  In the case of Cucumber or any other BDD-based framework, you would only refer to what you are now calling "main" as "steps" and each test would have its own story file, accessing the one, or more, steps files.  The rest remains the same.  The idea behind that is it allows you to create and maintain a library of related steps that existing and future story files can refer to.

Hope this has helped you and/or others to better understand the flow.  Also, disclaimer - most of this is my opinion - there are likely many ways to diagram the relationships, but what I described is what I use.

Upon further examination, I see that I missed the lower half (I am visually impaired).  The testrunner is typically at the very top of the chain in this environment.  It runs as a single JUnit or TestNG test to run ALL your stories.

And now my browser is messed-up and I cannot re-scroll back up to confirm that diagram again to comment more.

I've drawn a crude layout of what I was trying to describe.  I hope it explains my answer to your question more clearly.

[image: Layout Diagram]

Here's the basic project tree:

[image: Basic Project Tree]

Here's src/test/java expanded:

[image: src/test/java expanded]

And finally, src/test/resources expanded

[image: src/test/resources expanded]

The only thing in \src\main\resources is some extra stuff that JBehave uses to allow some customization of their reports, called FTL.

Comment: from your experience, what would you change in the setup of my Maven project (New image i have attached above)?

Comment: You're close, but there are a few incorrect assumptions, I think.  I will post a screenshot of one of my projects in my original answer to help clarify.  Note that page objects are classes like tests, and the actions and locators are typically stored in the same class, so there's no breakdown there.

Comment: honestly thanks for going out of your way to provide me with some examples, I really appreciate it

Comment: Glad to help, Gbru

Comment: sorry to bombard you will questions any more suggestions for the final setup (Updated Image)? thanks again

Comment: My example is not carved in stone, just an example.  There are a lot of experts who I am sure are happy to offer help.  Post any additional questions here or as another question.  I can't think of anything else at the moment.  I do not have first-hand experience with Cucumber, just JBehave, so some of my suggestions/answers might be off-base.  If so, my peers will likely step in and correct me.  They both use the Gherkin syntax, but beyond that, I don't know that they work quite the same.

Comment: ok @Bill Hileman thanks again for your help, hope you have a great day